# What does the event keyword really do?

Tags: c#, events

```
public delegate void SecondChangedHandler(
        object clock, 
        TimeInfoEventArgs timeInformation);

    public event SecondChangedHandler SecondChanged;
```

I have written a clock based on this [article](http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_delegates_and_events.html).
Now if i remove the event keyword i get the same result, so what does event really do?

Answer (score 16):

It's compiled differently. It makes it so someone can't do

```
mySecondChangedHandler.SecondChanged = SomeMethod(...); //overwrite
mySecondChangedHandler.SecondChanged(...); //invoke
```

but only

```
mySecondChangedHandler.SecondChanged += SomeMethod(...);
mySecondChangedHandler.SecondChanged -= SomeMethod(...);
```

Comment: that's really the answear i was looking for! :D you are a life saver :)

Comment: go ahead a click the checkbox next to the answer to accept it. This makes it easier for others to find a solution when searching.

Answer (score 6):

The `event` keyword creates a **private** delegate field, and a pair of public [*event accessors*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882534.aspx) called `add_EventName` and `remove_EventName`.  ([details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664455%28v=vs.71%29.aspx))

This means that writing `EventName` inside the class returns the delegate instance, allowing you to call or inspect the event handlers.

Outside the class, `EventName` doesn't really exist; all you can do is write `EventName += something` and `EventName -= something`, and the compiler will convert it into calls to the accessors.  (like a property)

For more details, see [this series of blog posts](http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Amsdn.com+%22Events+get+a+little+overhaul+in+C%23+4%22).

Answer (score 2):

The event keyword does two things

- It supplied permissions. Only the class can raise the event, however any external method can invoke the raw delegate
- It provides metadata which can be used for designers and the like

Answer (score 2):

The `event` keywords means only methods on the instance that hosts the SecondChanged field can invoke it. External attempts will fail.

Answer (score 1):

The `event` keyword creates a pair of *accessors* for a delegate.  These are effectively two methods (`add` and `remove`) that are called when you *subscribe* or *unsubscribe* from the event.

In your case, you're creating a "field-like event".  The compiler makes a delegate behind the scenes, and allows you to subscribe and unsubscribe from it's invocation list.  This means that you have all of the functionality of a delegate, but you're restricting access so that that outside world can "handle" the event, but not raise the event (invoke the delegate).

You can, however, also explicitly create your own accessors for an event, and these can do other things (though that's not typically recommended unless there is a good reason to do so).

Answer (score -1):

Quote from [C# lang reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/event) about keyword `event`,

> Events are a special kind of multicast delegate that can only be invoked from within the class or struct where they are declared (the publisher class).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30409590)